# How to render different result in single <td> tag depending on double value in thymeleaf

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a table where I want to render different values in a `<td>` HTML tag according to my `prod.price`. For example when the `prod.price < 1` I want to show `0.30 c`. When `prod.price > 1` Thymeleaf should render `1.20 aws`.

My current implementation, unfortunately, shows both `aws` and `c` when the `prod.price < 1`. For example if the price is `0.30c` my solution will render both `0.30c` and `0.30aws`. I am not sure what is wrong and why it gives me this result and some help figuring out this would be appreciated. The implementation I have now looks like this -

```
<td th:text="${prod.name}"></td>
            <td>
                <span th:if="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} &lt; 1">
                <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' clouds'"></span>
            </span> 
                <span th:unless="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} &gt; 1"></span>
                <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' aws'"></span>

            </td>
```

I also played a lot with the `<span>` tags, but I did not achieve much success. My initial approach, in the beginning, is below but is also not working.

```
            <td>
            <span th:if="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} &lt; 1" th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' clouds'"></span>
            <span th:unless="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} &gt; 1" th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' aws'"></span>

            </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wereclose. This should work:

```
<td>
    <span th:if="$prod.price} &lt; 1" 
          th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' clouds'">
    </span>
    <span th:if="${prod.price} &gt; 1" 
          th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')} + ' aws'">
    </span>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Saved my day! I knew it was some really minor error

Comment: I'm happy to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just like to offer some alternatives to simplify/avoid repeated code. . (And just some info... instead of using `&gt;` you can also use the text alternatives as shown [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#comparators-and-equality).)

```
<td>
  <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}" />
  <span th:text="${prod.price GT 1 ? 'aws' : 'cloud'}" />
</td>
```

If you did want to use `th:if` / `th:unless`, note that you should be using the same boolean expression in both.  It's because you used `< 1` in the `th:if` and `> 1` in the `th:unless` that your solution would always print `aws` and `c`.

```
<td>
  <span th:text="${#numbers.formatDecimal(prod.price, 1, 'COMMA', 2, 'POINT')}" />
  <span     th:if="${prod.price GT 1}">aws<span>
  <span th:unless="${prod.price GT 1}">cloud<span>
</td>
```